# Image-Charts Line Fill only fills color through y=0, not to bottom of chart

Tags: image-charts

How do I get the Image-Charts line fill feature to fill the area under the line to the bottom of the chart, even when there are negative values?

The line fill feature: `chm=B,color,series_index,0,0` 
is supposed to fill the area under a line through the bottom of the chart. It does this in the google version. But, in Image-Charts, rather than coloring the area under a line to the bottom of a chart, it acts as an area chart - which creates an issue when the values are negative. It fills the area between the line and the y=0 (example image is below).

Has anyone figured out how to force it to fill through to the bottom of the chart, even when there are negative values? Or any ideas on other ways to approach within Image-Charts?

[Example image of line fill stopping at y=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaE5s.png)

Comment: What kind of chart and data-format are you using? Here is an example: https://image-charts.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=700x300&chd=a:10,25,30,-40,12,48,100,20&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|Jan|&chm=B,FCECF4,0,0,0&chco=E4061C&chma=0,0,0,5

Comment: Chart type is sparkline (cht=ls:nda) and using basic text format. I am able to get the chart you shared as an example. The issue is that I want the line fill to fill in all of the area below the line to the bottom of the chart. I don't want it to be centered around 0, as yours is.

Comment: We've fixed it, see my answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your report!

We've updated our test suite and [deployed a fix](https://www.image-charts.com/):

[image: google image charts alternative]

See [our changelog](https://headwayapp.co/image-charts-changelog/fixed-line-chart-fill-bellow-0-93372).